# Mgo (mongo for go) support for materialized paths?

Tags: mongodb, go, bson, mgo, database

With BSON and Mgo(rich mongodb driver for go), how would one approach implementing materialized paths?

Materialized paths are documented [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-materialized-paths/) on the mongo docs. Materialized paths are designed to provide a tree-like structure for multiple levels of nested data.

With plain javascript, the command are as follows (from the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-materialized-paths/)):

```
db.categories.insert( { _id: "Books", path: null } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "Programming", path: ",Books," } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "Databases", path: ",Books,Programming," } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "Languages", path: ",Books,Programming," } )
```

Created collection 'categories' with the following entries

```
Books > Programming > Databases
Books > Programming > Languages
```

And can be queried using:

```
db.categories.find( { path: /,Programming,/ } )
```

Will find the two entries which are both decendants of programming.

How do I implement this using **Mgo** and **BSON**?

There is no such documentation in the Mgo docs. I have tried attempts such as

```
result := []bson.M{}
database.C("categories").Find(bson.M{"path": "/,Programming,/"}).All(&result)
fmt.Println(result)
```

Only to return an empty array `[]`

Any gophers and mongo lovers to enlighten me here?

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to look into how to pass a regular expression into your query. Path is stored as a string and ````/,Programming,/```` is regular expression.

Comment: @Martin Hmm.. Okay! I am looking into it right now.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this part in **mgo/bson** documentation: http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson#RegEx

It should probably look like this

```
database.C("categories").Find(bson.M{"path": &bson.RegEx{Pattern: ",Programming,", Options: "i"}}).All(&result)
```